# Carousel implemente next and previous buttons in WEB React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, slider, carousel

Im trying to add next and previous buttons in this carousel. In ios and Android it works! But on Web no...
I need this two buttons for react native expo in web.

Any help?

The images that I send are arrays from expo Image Picker, it only contains the uri (url).
example of url:
["file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E602...jpg", "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E603...jpg"]

```js
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image, useWindowDimensions, ViewabilityConfig, ViewToken, Platform, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import colors from '../../theme/colors';
import Button from '../Button';

interface ICarousel {
  images: string[];

}

const CarouselUploadMemories = ({ images }: ICarousel) => {
 
  const [activeImageIndex, setActiveImageIndex] = useState(0);
  const viewabilityConfig: ViewabilityConfig = {
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 0,
  }
  const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }: { viewableItems: Array<ViewToken> }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
      setActiveImageIndex(viewableItems[0].index || 0);
    }
  });


  const slideList = images.map((image, i) => {
    return {
      id: i.toString(),
      image
    };
  });

  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slideList.length;
  const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>();

  const goNextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current < length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0);
    flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({ index: current, animated: true });
  };
  const goPrevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current ? current - 1 : length - 1);
    flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({ index: current, animated: true });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({ index: current, animated: true });
  }, [current]);


  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <Button text='next' onPress={goNextSlide} />
      <Button text='previous' onPress={goPrevSlide} />
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={slideList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{}}>
            {item &&
              <Image
                source={{ uri: item.image }}
                style={{
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  width: 500,
                  maxHeight: 500,
                  marginRight: 5,
                  resizeMode: 'cover',
                }}
              />
            }
          </View>
        )}
        horizontal={true}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged.current}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "center",
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: 0,
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        {images && images.map((_, index) => (
          <View
            key={index}
            style={{
              width: 12,
              aspectRatio: 1,
              borderRadius: 7,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: index ? colors.lightGray : colors.lightGray,
              backgroundColor:
                activeImageIndex === index ? colors.black : colors.lightGray,
              margin: 10,
              marginHorizontal: 5,
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}


export default CarouselUploadMemories
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create Carousel in React Native using FlatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438848/create-carousel-in-react-native-using-flatlist)

Comment: @user18309290 It helped me a little! and thanks to that I have been able to do it on iOS and Android. But on the Web it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I update the code @user18309290